# Alamofire response return nil but work on Postman

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I have parameter :

```
{"name": "oaseme dabo", "spouseName": "", "fatherName": "hajime kasuga", "income": "Please Choose", "homeAddress": "", "locationAccessibility": "Please Choose", "gender": "Please Choose", "exactOccupation": "", "maritalStatus": "Please Choose", "source_id": "123456", "dateOfBirth": "01 January 1900", "exactIncome": "1", "howInfluenceThisPerson": "Please Choose", "motherName": "shizuka kasuga", "knowThisPerson": "Please Choose", "prospectingStatus": "Please Choose", "ageBand": "Choose Age Band", "occupation": "Please Choose", "sourceOfProspect": "Family & Relatives", "agentCode": "123456", "totalChildren": "0", "howCloseAreYou": "Please Choose", "workAddress": "", "exactSourceOfProspect": ""}
```

I put it into body :

```
class func sentContactBody(agentCode: String, source_id: String, dateOfBirth: String, ageBand: String, exactIncome: String, exactOccupation: String, fatherName: String, gender: String, homeAddress: String, howCloseAreYou: String, howInfluenceThisPerson: String, income: String, knowThisPerson: String, locationAccessibility: String, maritalStatus: String, motherName: String, name: String, occupation: String, prospectingStatus: String, sourceOfProspect: String, spouseName: String, totalChildren: String, workAddress: String, exactSourceOfProspect: String) -> Parameters{
    let sentContact : Parameters = [
        "agentCode": agentCode,
        "source_id": source_id,
        "dateOfBirth": dateOfBirth,
        "ageBand": ageBand,
        "exactIncome": exactIncome,
        "exactOccupation": exactOccupation,
        "fatherName": fatherName,
        "gender": gender,
        "homeAddress": homeAddress,
        "howCloseAreYou": howCloseAreYou,
        "howInfluenceThisPerson": howInfluenceThisPerson,
        "income": income,
        "knowThisPerson": knowThisPerson,
        "locationAccessibility": locationAccessibility,
        "maritalStatus": maritalStatus,
        "motherName": motherName,
        "name": name,
        "occupation": occupation,
        "prospectingStatus": prospectingStatus,
        "sourceOfProspect": sourceOfProspect,
        "spouseName": spouseName,
        "totalChildren": totalChildren,
        "workAddress": workAddress,
        "exactSourceOfProspect": exactSourceOfProspect
    ]

    return sentContact
}
```

and I called it as param :

```
let param = HTTPBody.sentContactBody(agentCode: agentCode, source_id: source_id, dateOfBirth: dateOfBirth, ageBand: ageBand, exactIncome: exactIncome, exactOccupation: exactOccupation, fatherName: fatherName, gender: gender, homeAddress: homeAddress, howCloseAreYou: howCloseAreYou, howInfluenceThisPerson: howInfluenceThisPerson, income: income, knowThisPerson: knowThisPerson, locationAccessibility: locationAccessibility, maritalStatus: maritalStatus, motherName: motherName, name: name, occupation: occupation, prospectingStatus: prospectingStatus, sourceOfProspect: sourceOfProspect, spouseName: spouseName, totalChildren: totalChildren, workAddress: workAddress, exactSourceOfProspect: exactSourceOfProspect)
```

when I used Alamofire to called, it always return nil so it count as failure:

```
Alamofire.request(Constant.sentContactSAMDB(), method: .post, parameters: param, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: ConnectionManager.sharedIns.getHTTPHeadersSAMDB())
        .responseObject{ (response: DataResponse<SAMDBModel>) in
            switch(response.result) {
            case .success(_):
                print("contact response result value:\(response.result.value)")
                if response.result.value != nil {
                    self.samDBModel = response.result.value
                    let status = self.samDBModel?.status
                    let statusCode = response.response?.statusCode
                    print("sent contact statusCode:\(String(describing: statusCode))")
                    if(statusCode == 200){
                        let result = self.samDBModel?.result
                        let samDBStatus = result![0].status
                        let samDBError = result![0].error
                        print("sent contact samDBStatus:\(samDBStatus)")
                    }
                }
                break

            case .failure(_):
                print("contact failure response result value:\(response.result.value)")
                self.samDBModel = response.result.value
                let status = self.samDBModel?.status ?? "Failed connect to Tokio Marine server"
                break

            }
    }
```

But it works on Postman:
[image]

the headers is only Content-Type : application/json

What is the correct code to make it work? I already put plist exception domain and allow arbitary loads YES.

Comment: @Adrian endpoint: http://api-samuat.tokiomarine-life.co.id/activities/contact/

Comment: can try encoding: URLEncoding.default

Comment: @ZahirulIslam , URLEncoding.default also got contact failure response result value:nil

Comment: Is this your first time using Alamofire? Instead of deserialising it to DataResponse<SAMDBModel> try to use DataResponse<Data> . Or instead of . responseObject  use .responseJSON then cast the response.result manually. I believe it is the deserializing part is the problem

Comment: @AndrewJamesRamirez, I try with .responseJSON{ (response) in also got contact failure response result value:nil

Comment: @Sarimin try checking the status code 

Alamofire.request(request).responseJSON { response in 
   print(response.response?.statusCode)
}

Comment: @AndrewJamesRamirez, print("JSON STATUS CODE:\(response.response?.statusCode)") return JSON STATUS CODE:nil

Comment: Show your model `SAMDBModel` and try responseJSON for testing to verify that you are able to get JSON or not. Also try responseString too let me know

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya, it seems problem with exception domains, it receive domain only. not with http://, after I replace it with domain only it can get response

Answer (score 3):

set request body and header properly like this:

```
let data = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: your_parameters, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted)
var request = URLRequest(url: your_URL)
request.httpBody = data
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
```

Comment: thanks. it already solved, because of http:// inside exception domain. your answer also good use of NSURLSession

Answer (score 0):

let param:[String:Any] = ["key":"Value"]

```
request(url, method: method, parameters: param, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: yourheader).responseJSON { (response) in 
       if(response.result.isSuccess){
        }
       else{
        }
}
```

This will give you proper json converted response.
On second thought please confirm all parameter and header types from API side.

Comment: thanks. It is already solved because of http:// inside exception domain.